# unsigned int vs unsigned long both are 32bit but I can't intermix them without casting... why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

My computer shows the `sizeof` `unsigned long` and `unsigned int` to be the same.

However when passing in arguments to methods... more specifically pointers... I must recast the `unsigned int` as an `unsigned long`.  Otherwise a build error of `Compiler Error C2664":'function' : cannot convert argument n from 'type1' to 'type2'`

Why?

Comment: Because they are different types.  Just like `struct Foo { int x; }` and `struct Bar { int x; }` are different types, even though they have the same layout.

Comment: they are different types, also the size is implementation defined [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Comment: Implicit conversions don't work through pointers.

Comment: An example of code that produces that error would help make this question more useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

They are completely unrelated types as far as the compiler is concerned. Passing a pointer of *any* type except the one the argument expects is an error.

But even if the compiler was made to recognize that this type of pointer cast is possible and do it for you, here's why that would be bad...

C++ has been around long enough that `int` and `long` have changed size as new CPU architectures come and go. The size of `int` and `long` depends on the compiler and platform you're working with so, casting `int*` into `long*` (or vice versa) can lead you right into a [all sorts of problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) if they are *not* the same size.

According to the [C++ standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) these are the sizes of `int` and `long` across various platforms:

```
type | C++ standard | LP32 | ILP32 | LLP64 | LP64
-------------------------------------------------
int  | at least 16  | 16   | 32    | 32    | 32      bits
long | at least 32  | 32   | 32    | 32    | 64      bits
```

Only with ILP32 and LLP64 can you safely assume that `int` and `long` are the same size, but supporting that assumption in the compiler would allow you to write code that does not compile or run safely on the other platforms.

Lastly, if you need a guarantee that the size of an integer is the same across all platforms, then you can [`#include <cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and use types such as `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t`, etc. These fixed-width integers are available with compilers that support C++11 and later.